# Determine which parameter failed in a Lucene BooleanQuery?

Tags: java, lucene

I need to determine which part of a Lucene BooleanQuery failed if the entire query returns no results.

I'm using a `BooleanQuery` made up of 4 `NumericRangeQueries` and a `PhraseQuery`. Each is added to the query with `Occur.MUST`.

If I don't get any results for a query, is there a way to tell which part of the query failed to match anything? Do I need to run queries individually and compare results to get the one that failed?

Edit - Added `PhraseQuery` code.

```
if( row.getPropertykey_tx() != null && !row.getPropertykey_tx().trim().isEmpty()){
    PhraseQuery pQuery = new PhraseQuery();
    String[] words = row.getPropertykey_tx().trim().split(" ");
    for( String word : words ){
        pQuery.add(new Term(TitleRecordColumns.SA_SITE_ADDR.toString(), word));
    }
    pQuery.setSlop(2);

    topBQuery.add(pQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running individual parts of the query is probably the simplest approach, to my mind.

Another tool available is the getting an [Explaination](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Explanation.html).  You can call [`IndexSearcher.explain`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29) to get an Explanation of the scoring for the query against a particular document.  If you can provide the docid of a document you believe should match the query, you can analyze `Explanation.toString` (or `toHtml`, if you prefer) to determine which subqueries are not matching against it.

---

If you want to automatically keep a record of which clause of a BooleanQuery doesn't produce results, I believe you will need to run each query independantly.  If you no longer have access to the subqueries used to create it, you can get the clauses of it instead:

```
findTroublesomeQuery(BooleanQuery query) {
    for (BooleanClause clause : query.clauses()) {
        Query subquery = clause.getQuery()
        TopDocs docs = searchHoweverYouDo(subquery);
        if  (doc.totalSize == 0) {
            //If you want to dig down recursively...
            if (subquery instanceof BooleanQuery)
                findTroublesomeQuery(query);
            else 
                log(query); //Or do whatever you want to keep track of it.
        }
    }
}
```

[`DisjunctionMaxQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DisjunctionMaxQuery.html) is a commonly used query that wraps multiple subqueries as well, so might be worth considering for this sort of approach.

Comment: I added the code to create my `PhraseQuery`. The index is about 13 million records. I don't know the specific document ID of any one entry. What I want to do is log anything that doesn't produce results so I can analyze that later.

Comment: Looks like you are approaching the `PhraseQuery` the right way, I'd still be concerned about analysis there though.  If the field uses `StandardAnalyzer`, for instance, Punctuation, upper-case characters, etc. could be problematic, if it isn't being further normalized elsewhere.

Comment: It does use `StandardAnalyzer` but I'm cutting out an punctuation elsewhere in my code. So I think I'm okay there. And thank you! The code snippet you provided is very helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you have the right things in mind on the `PhraseQuery`, certainly could be mistaken on my guess.

Comment: I implemented your code and I'm finding, like you predicted, the `PhraseQuery` is the one that causes most of the `BooleanQueries` to fail. Thanks again!